# Sent USDC to wrong chain on gnosis. Need to recover

Tags: gnosis-safe

I accidentally sent funds on the CRONOS chain from crypto.com to gnosis safe (instead of ETH). I can see the funds on cronoscan - how can I retrieve the funds as gnosis doens't support CRO.

Comment: See https://foresightnews.pro/article/detail/10296

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the destination of those funds. If you sent them to one of your EOA wallets, then that's already solved since you would still own that same wallet address on all chains.

If you sent them to a multisig wallet like a Gnosis Safe, then recovering those funds might be more tricky. You would need to attempt to generate that Gnosis Safe deterministically since a Gnosis Safe is a smart contract.

I recommend reading the article shared by Mikko, as it provides exact details for how a hacker was able to gain access to 20 million OP tokens because the team sent them to an address for a Gnosis Safe that only existed on Ethereum Mainnet. The hacker was able to access those funds by generating the same Gnosis Safe address on the Optimism chain deterministically. I would suggest you try a similar approach to recover your funds. But be careful, you will not get a second chance to recover your funds if you happen to deploy the wrong smart contract code to that address.

Answer (score 0):

If the wallet address is same that you own in ethereum chain then by default you own same wallet in all other EVM based chains like binance smart chain, polygon, avax etc. Just add the json rpc in your metamask to recover the funds.